# Executing SQL Server stored procedure in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API returns -1

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API project and I am attempting to execute an existing stored procedure in SQL Server.

However, it always returns `-1` instead of the Id that it is supposed to return. This is my first attempt at using ASP.NET Core and I am struggling to understand it.

This is the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_CheckForExistingEmployee]
    (@FirstName varchar(100),
     @LastName varchar(100), 
     @SSN varchar(3), 
     @MDOB int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 Id 
    FROM tbl_Employees
    WHERE Firstname = @FirstName 
      AND LastName = @LastName 
      AND COALESCE(SSN, @SSN) = @SSN 
      AND COALESCE(MDOB, @MDOB) = @MDOB
END
```

This is my C# code:

```
public async Task<int> CheckForExistingEmployee(EmployeeImport model)
{
    object[] parameters =
            {
                new SqlParameter("@FirstName", model.FirstName),
                new SqlParameter("@LastName", model.LastName),
                new SqlParameter("@SSN", model.SSN),
                new SqlParameter("@MDOB", model.MDOB)
            };

    var exists = await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("stp_CheckForExistingEmployee  {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", parameters);

    return exists;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but if you are using an `TOP(1)` you should be using an `ORDER BY`; otherwise you'll be getting any arbitrary value. Also, instead of `COALESCE(SSN, @SSN) = @SSN` you should be using syntax like `AND (SSN = @SSN OR @SSN IS NULL)` and including `RECOMPILE` in your `OPTION` clause. See [Revisiting catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/)

Comment: Well what is Id `-1` and why would it return that? Does it fit with the parameters? Side point: you should explicitly define which parameters you are passing `"EXEC stp_CheckForExistingEmployee @FirstName = {0}, @LastNaem = {1}....`

Comment: I don't know why it returns -1, that is the question.  The Id it should return is 56939.  And I tried using @FirstName, etc. instead of {0}, etc., but I received the same result.  Inputting parameters directly in the sproc returns the expected result.  It just is not working from Core.

Comment: From the docs I think `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` returns the number of rows affected. Not the resultset as you are trying to do. I think you would be better off using an output parameter since its a single value.

Answer (score -2):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_CheckForExistingEmployee]
    (@FirstName varchar(100),
     @LastName varchar(100), 
     @SSN varchar(3), 
     @MDOB int,
     @id int output)
AS
BEGIN
    set @id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id 
    FROM tbl_Employees
    WHERE Firstname = @FirstName 
      AND LastName = @LastName 
      AND COALESCE(SSN, @SSN) = @SSN 
      AND COALESCE(MDOB, @MDOB) = @MDOB) 

    return @id
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that did not help.

Comment: A complete answer explains what has changed in addition to providing working code.

Comment: And the `return` statement is **intended** to return the status of the SP, not a value as such. For a value an output parameter should be used.